# Command Prompt "dir /b /s > file.txt" need to remove directories from results

Tags: command, prompt

I am using the following command to dump the complete file listings recursively from a directory.

dir /b /s c:\myfolder > c:\mylist.txt

This works fine but it is display the results with the full path as well, beacuse I am using a regex expression on the results I need them to display only the filenames.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to get the filename from the entire path.

If you can use powershell, look at `Get-ChildItem`. You can have more powerful options with it.

Comment: I am using findstr with the command findstr /r /x /C:".*[^a-zA-Z0-9_ ./-].*" filelist.txt

Comment: Im not sure how to change what i am doing with the regex command.  I am generating the text file with the filenames in it using dir

Comment: @ fightstarr20 `/C:string  Uses specified string as a literal search string.` Why are you using `/C` when you want to use a regex?

Comment: @fightstarr20  - what do you really want to do? Just get all filenames?

Answer (score 8):

Kind of an old question but if someone stumbles across this hoping for an answer, perhaps this will help them out.

Running this from the windows command line (CMD.exe) use:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion    
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /s c:\myfolder"') do (@echo %~nxa >>c:\mylist.txt)
endlocal
```

Running this from a windows .BAT script use:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion    
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s c:\myfolder"') do (@echo %%~nxa >>c:\mylist.txt)
endlocal
```

The output might look something like this depending on what files are in the folder you're running the code in:

```
file1.fil
file2.fil
file3.fil
```

UNDERSTANDING WHAT THE CODE IS DOING

> for /f

- means to run a loop through files in this case using the `dir /b /s` command to help get those files names from directories (folders) and subdirectories (subfolders).  As stated in the question, this will give you complete paths to the files. So instead of file.txt you will get C:\folder\file.txt.

> "delims="

- in this case tells the for loop that it wants the variable %a or %%a
  to only have 1 folderpath and filename for every loop.

> %a (CMD.exe) %%a (.BAT)

- as mentioned above is a variable that changes with each loop. so
  everytime the command `dir /b /s` finds a new filename the variable
  %%a changes to the filename.
- example: 
  Loop 1:  %%a = c:\folder\file1.fil
  Loop 2:  %%a = c:\folder\file2.fil

> dir /b /s

- is the command to print out the files of a directory (folder). By
  using the `/b` and `/s` the questioner is adding additional criteria.
  the command `dir` not only prints out the files and directories
  (folders) in that directory (folder) but also some additional
  information about the directory.

  - the `/b` tells the command dir that it doesn't want the additional
    information.. just the filenames.
  - The `/s` tells the command dir to include all the files and
    subdirectories (subfolders) in that folder.

> do

- is the part of the loop that tells what to do during that particular
  loop.   So in this case it is only doing this one command every loop
  `(@echo %%~nxa >>c:\mylist.txt)`

> @echo

- is a simple command that prints out whatever you want either to your
  computer screen or in this case to a txt file by using `@echo %%~nxa
  >>c:\mylist.txt`
- the `>>` before c:\mylist.txt is especially important. Every time a
  loop happens it starts a new line in the txt file and writes the
  variable to that line. If only one `>` is specified it will overwrite
  the line in the txt file everytime the loop happens. Which will
  defeat the purpose of what this script is designed to do.

> %~nxa (CMD.exe) %%~nxa (.BAT)

- is the variable %%a as mentioned above except it is parsed (edited)
  out the way the questioner @fightstarr20 asked for.  Instead of
  printing out the variable as  C:\myfolder\myfile.fil the variable
  will print out as myfile.fil
- the `~` in `%%~nxa` tells the program you want to modify the variable 
  %%a. In this case by adding `n` and `x`.
- the `n` in `%%~nxa` tells the program you want to modify the variable %%a by
  excluding the path from the variable.

  - example.

    ```
         -variable %%a = C:\folder\filename.fil 
         -variable %%~na = filename.
    ```

    -If you notice however that it leaves the extension .fil off of the filename.
- the `x` in `%%~nxa` tells the program you want to modify the variable %%a
  by excluding the path and the filename from the variable, so all you will get is the extension of the filename.

  - example.

    ```
         -variable %%a = C:\folder\filename.fil
         -variable %%~xa = .fil
    ```
- so if you combine both of the modifiers `n` and `x` to the variable %%a
  you will get the full filename including the extension.

  - example:

    ```
         -variable %%a = c:\folder\filename.fil
         -variable %%~nxa = filename.fil
    ```

> setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

- explained simply is a command that needs to be in the script before
  the for loop in order to allow the variable %%a to be modified or "expanded".

> endlocal

- this turns off the setlocal enabledelayedexpansion command

To get a very helpful explanation and reference for CMD commands I recommend reading [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/) and for a great forum to get CMD answers I'd recommend [dostips.com](http://www.dostips.com/)

Comment: Almost 5 years later, this is still helpful. Thank you for the breakdown as well! Aces!

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this

```
dir /b /s C:\myfolder>C:\temp.txt
echo exit>>C:\temp.txt
goto loop

:loop
set /p _x=<temp.txt
findstr /v /c:"%_x%" temp.txt>temp2.txt
type temp2.txt>temp.txt
set _x=%_x:*\=%
echo %_x%>file.txt
if "%_x%" == "exit" (
del temp.txt
del temp2.txt
exit
)
goto loop
```

You can use for instead of goto if you like, but it will be basicaly the same.
Sorry about the last one...

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but it hurts me that nobody said to take away the /s

```
dir /b c:\myfolder > c:\mylist.txt
```

That should do it.

Comment: It's late, but without /s it will not scan subdirs and i'm sure the user wanted it

Answer (score 0):

This would surely work, as it works for me.

dir D:(Path to files) /s /b >d:\filelist.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this code:

```
dir /b > A_fileslist.txt
```

Copy inside a notepad editor and save as "Fileslist.bat".